# Based on same physical plan, why the spark sql is much faster than dataframe when i using WHERE to filter data from hive partitioned table?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, dask-dataframe

**Describes**

I have a hive partitioned table (`table1` for example) which has 4 partitioned columns, and when I using spark-shell to filter the table with the first two partitioned columns(`project` and `date`), I got different performance. Using **spark sql** to execute sql is **much faster** than **spark dataframe's `WHERE`**, and what's even weirder is that they have same physical plan.

And I have checked the Spark Web UI, showing that the input and output recoders and data size for those two job(one is spark sql, one is dataframe) are same too.

So, it confuses me so much. I think that with the same physical plan, it should have same performance.And hope your help, thanks so much.

Here are some details:

```
hive version: 1.1.0-cdh5.8.5
spark version: 2.1.0.cloudera2
scala version: 2.11.8
jdk version: 1.8.0_181
hive table partitioned columns: project,date,type,section
hive table file format: SequenceFile
```

This is the code I ran on spark-shell base on yarn:

```scala
scala> spark.sql("select * from table1 where project='a' and `date`='b'").explain
== Physical Plan ==
HiveTableScan [...other table columns...., project#176, date#177, type#178, section#179], MetastoreRelation table1, [isnotnull(project#176), isnotnull(date#177), (project#176 = a), (date#177 = b)]

scala> spark.table("table1").where("project='a'").where("`date`='b'").explain
== Physical Plan ==
HiveTableScan [...other table columns..., project#195, date#196, type#197, section#198], MetastoreRelation table1, [isnotnull(project#195), (project#195 = a), isnotnull(date#196), (date#196 = b)]


// I have run those statements several times before, so it shouldn't be the cache problem
scala> spark.time(spark.sql("select * from table1 where project='a' and `date`='b'").count)
Time taken: 8146 ms                                                             
res10: Long = 45392

scala> spark.time(spark.table("table1").where("project='a'").where("`date`='b'").count)
Time taken: 513 ms
res11: Long = 45392
```

Spark Web UI snapshot:

Job 6(Dataframe):

[image: stage info for Job6]

[image: stage 11 detail for Job 6]

[image: stage 12 detail for Job 6]

Job 7 (Spark SQL):

[image: stage info for Job7]

[image: stage 13 detail for Job 7]

[image: stage 14 detail for Job 7]